# sequences of dyadic numbers that converge to non dyadic number

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

definition of dyadic number

> $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is called dyadic number if $\exists p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $x = \frac{p}{2^k}$

I am trying to prove following theorem

> assume that $x$ is *not* a dyadic number then there exists two sequences of dyadic numbers $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ and  $x_n < x < y_n$ for all n s.t $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$

here is my attempt can someone verify following argument

- since x is not a dyadic number there exists  $x_0$ and $y_0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ st $x_0 < x < y_0$
- now we will inductively define rest of the sequences as follows
- let $c_n = (x_n + y_n)/2$
- there are two possible cases $x_{n-1}<x<c_{n-1}$ or $c_{n-1} < x < y_{n-1}$
- if $x_{n-1}<x<c_{n-1}$ then $x_n = x_{n-1}$ and $y_n = c_{n-1}$
- if $c_{n-1} < x < y_{n-1}$ then $x_n = c_{n-1}$ and $y_n = y_{n-1}$

now we will prove that it satisfies all required properties

- first $x_0$ and $y_0$ are dyadic numbers. $x_n$ and $y_n$ are dyadic numbers $\forall n\geq 1$ because addition of two dyadic number is dyadic number and dividing a dyadic number by $2$ produces dyadic number again
- $x_n < y_n$ by construction
- now we will prove that $\lim x_n = x = \lim y_n$
- first observe that length of the interval $[x_n , y_n]$ goes to zero i.e., $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |y_n - x_n| = 0$
- so forall $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ s.t $\forall n \geq N$ $|y_n - x_n| < \epsilon$
- we know that $x \in (x_n , y_n)$ $\forall n$
- which implies that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ and $|y_n - y| < \epsilon$ $\forall n \geq N$
- so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$
- we are done.

Comment: Looks good.  In the bullet "so there exists" I would start with "Given an $\epsilon \gt 0$".  You can even compute it by saying you need $n$ large enough that $\frac {y_0-x_0}{2^n} \lt \epsilon$ but that is not required.

Comment: @RossMillikan can you write an answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good. In the bullet "so there exists" I would start with "Given an $\epsilon \gt 0$". You can even compute it by saying you need $n$ large enough that $\frac {y_0−x_0}{2^n} \lt \epsilon$ but that is not required.